# pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, systemd, debian-buster

I just upgraded a Debian system from stretch to buster and systemd isn't starting the sshd daemon. I can start and stop the daemon via /etc/init.d/sshd [start|stop] but shortly after that, the daemon dies. *journalctl* reports this error near the end of my log *Failed to connect to system bus*. starting sshd via */usr/sbin/sshd -ddd* works fine.

```
pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory
```

I've [had issues in the past](https://serverfault.com/questions/941855/why-am-i-missing-var-run-sshd-after-every-boot) with systemd and ssh and this seems like a different problem. I"ve added /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf (which was missing) with this:

```
# cat /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf                                                                                                                           
d /run/sshd 0755 root root
```

but when I run *systemd-tmpfiles --create* I get this error. It looks like this is saying something is wrong with the Nagios systemd configuration....which is screwing up sshd..? the directories /var/run/nagios and /run/nagios both exist. Anyone have an interpretation for this error message?

```
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/nagios-nrpe-server.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/nagios → /run/nagios; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
```